# How to check via conditional tags for a single plugin page?

Tags: plugin-development, conditional-tags, wp-enqueue-style

I am developing a plugin. To embed the stylesheet I used `wp_enqueue_style()`. I want the CSS file to be only implemented at the plugin's page. I have already seen solutions with conditional tags, but neither `is_page()` nor `is_admin()` are fitting my request. I am able to implement the stylesheet only in the backend, but it is possible to implement it only on the plugin's page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this part of the WP Codex: [Loading scripts only on plugin pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_scripts_only_on_plugin_pages).

The key is to hook in on the `admin_print_styles-{page}` action. The {page} part, aka hook suffix, is returned from the [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) function.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, did oversee it! Thank you :-)